# bmi calculator is giving me the wrong conversion not sure why

Tags: python

```
from colorama import Fore


def bmi_calc():
    pounds = float(input('What is your weight lbs ?'))
    height = int(input('What is your height in inches ?'))
    pounds = 703 * pounds
    height = height**2
    bmi = round(pounds / height)

    if bmi <= 16:
        print('Severely Underweight')
        print(Fore.RED + ' Seek Medical Attention')

    elif 16 <= bmi < 18.5:
        print('Underweight')

    elif bmi >= 18.5 < 25:
    print('Healthy')

elif bmi >= 25 < 30:
    print('Overweight')

elif bmi >= 30:
    print('Severely Overweight')
    print(Fore.RED + ' Seek Medical Attention')

print(bmi )
```

bmi_calc()

What is your weight lbs ?190
What is your height in inches ?60
Healthy
37

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Apart from the indentation, you want to call bmi_calc().

Comment: `bmi >= 18.5 < 25` is the same as `(bmi >= 18.5) and (18.5 < 25)` which is the same as `(bmi >= 18.5) and True` and so boils down to `bmi >= 18.5`. I think you wanted `18.5 <= bmi < 25`.

Answer (score 0):

The exit code seems to indicate there aren't any syntax problems, so the code is doing what it should. I am not sure if this is the issue, but why do you have the following lines?

```
pounds = 703 * pounds
height = height**2
```

Might be why you're getting the wrong conversion.

Answer (score 0):

BMI is kg/m**2. To convert pounds to kg, multiply by 0.45359237. To convert inches to m, multiply by 0.0254. Do this:

```
pounds = 0.45359237 * pounds
height = (height * 0.0254)**2
bmi = round(pounds / height)
```

Keep in mind that by default `round` rounds to the closest integer. If you want one decimal of precision, do `bmi = round(pounds / height, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your elif statements (at least in the code you showed us) are not indented.  In Python, the indents are fundamentally important.  Unlike C or PhP or Java, they don't use braces {} to identify when a function starts or stops.  Instead, it is the indents that indicate when a function (or other code block) starts or stops so:

```
def myFunction():
     print(1)
     print(2)
```

is not the same as:

```
def myFunction():
    print(1)
print(2)
```

in the latter case, the second print statement is OUTSIDE of the function.